# Java eclipse IDE debug

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a beginner in using Eclipse IDE to create Java programs. I am trying to know how to debug step by step using Eclipse IDE. I am running the program below and added breakpoint on //line 7

both classes are in default package.

```
public class GoodDog {

     private int size;

     public void setSize(int s){
            size=s;
     }

     public int getSize(){
            return size;
     }

     void bark(){
        if (size > 60){
            System.out.println("Woof! Woof!");
        } 
        else if (size > 14){
            System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
        }
        else{
           System.out.println("Yip! Yip!");
        }
     }



  public class GoodDogTestDrive {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            GoodDog one=new GoodDog(); //line 7
            one.setSize(70);

            GoodDog two=new GoodDog();
            two.setSize(8);

            System.out.println("Dog one " + one.getSize());
            System.out.println("Dog two " + two.getSize());
            one.bark();
            two.bark();
       }

   }
```

When I click the f5 button during debug session in eclipse, it gives

> source not found exception.

**Why is this happening?**

Without any breakpoints added it gives result fine. I need to learn debug this program step by step and how it goes the execution. I am using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Refer this.. http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-13.htm

Comment: And this.. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: I have already referred that link when I got stuck with this debugging and that doesn't help with my problem

Comment: I googled and tried every link that I got in eclipse debugging. in the mentioned line 7 when i click the f5 button it still gives the classnotfound error

Comment: This is a hard one to debug over StackOverflow I think.  Try downloading eclipse again into a different location, and ensure you're setting up your project correctly and try again.

Comment: In the debug perspective, there should be a window listing any breakpoints that have been set. There might be a breakpoint, "ClassNotFoundException: caught and uncaught”. Disable it and try again.

Comment: Full error message please. What class is not found?

Comment: Also, which line is line 7?

Comment: Is eclipse configured to use the JDK or the JRE?

Comment: @Pablo Do a search for "line 7", it's commented in the code.

Comment: Either you're missing a bracket or your TestDrive class is inside the class you're trying to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've copied and pasted the code incorrectly into the question, you appear to be missing a bracket at the end of the `bark()` method to close of the class. Therefore you don't have 1 class inside another.